# Catch and process KeyPress/KeyDown without modifying text in TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, events, textbox, keyboard

I currently have the following event handler which catches the Ctrl+Enter key combo in my Form code:

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter && e.Control)
    {
        // Stuff
    }
}
```

I also have two non-ReadOnly TextBoxes in the form, one of which is multiline, while the other one isn't. Whenever I hit Ctrl+Enter, the event does get handled, but it also registers as an Enter keypress when the focus is in either TextBox. What I want to do is register the key combo *without* the Enter keypress modifying the text in either box. Is there any way I could go about doing this?

Comment: Did you set the Handled property to true before exiting from this event handler?

Comment: Just tried that - didn't make any difference

Comment: You should use `ProcessCmdKey`. See my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your best choice is use `ProcessCmdKey`: Just add this to your Form add it will work:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if (keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.Enter))
    {
        // Stuff
        return true;
    }
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use the [`PreviewKeyDown`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.previewkeydown%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event instead and set the [`IsInputKey`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.previewkeydowneventargs.isinputkey%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property accordingly:

```
private void Form1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter && e.Control)
    {
        // Stuff
        e.IsInputKey = false;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**: From the name of your handler, I guess you added it to the `Form`'s `KeyPress/KeyDown/PreviewKeyDown` event. Instead you should register the method I showed above with each `TextBox`'s `PreviewKeyDown` event.

To not destroy what already works for you, you may leave your code as it is and just add a handler to the `TextBox`'s `PreviewKeyDown` event where you set `IsInputKey` to false for the specified keys, but don't do your `// Stuff`.

Comment: I swear this should work, but now it's not even handling the event.

Comment: @crayzeedude Updated my answer. The last point should work best. Just tell the textboxes that Ctrl+Enter is not an input key for them and leave your already working code as it is.